# Share a Stand Alone Scanner Over Network?

Tags: networking, usb, scanner, scanning

My office just got a new ScanSnap S1500 scanner and I wanted to hook it up so 4 or 5 different computers can access it and use it just as if it was connected directly to their machine.

Is my only option to get something like [USB-over-Network](http://www.fabulatech.com/) or Remote-Scan? Does anyone have any experience using these programs? Is there a decent open source or less expensive alternative to these programs?

Answer (score 2):

i'm using [Capturix ScanShare](http://www.capturix.com/default.asp?product=css) myself, not free but less expensive (by a far cry) than Remote-Scan. it suits my needs and does the job. ScanShare is shareware, try before you buy.

Comment: Looks like a great alternative, but the ScanSnap doesn't use TWAIN drivers so ScanShare doesn't recognize it.

Comment: that's a pity :(

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to check out the 2X ApplicationServer Version 8 (just released); this new version includes a Universal Scanning feature, operating the same way as Remote Scan and allowing printing from hardware attached to client devices. At Remote Scan per user pricing levels, you'd be able to receive an entire 2X remote application delivery solution for the same price as you'd pay for just universal scanning with RemoteScan.

You can try 2X Universal Scanning yourself by downloading the free trial at: http://www.2x.com/applicationserver/download.html. Hopefully this should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you have a Linux, you can share it with sane. Your scanner is completely supported http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html#S-FUJITSU